# Nested transaction in SpringBatch tasklet not working

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, spring-batch

I'm using SpringBatch for my app. In one of the batch jobs, I need to process multiple data. Each data requires several database updates. And I need to make one transaction for one data. Meaning, if when processing one data an exception is thrown, database updates are rolled back for that data, then keep processing the next data.

I've put all database updates in one method in service layer. In my springbatch tasklet, I call that method for each data, like this;

```
for (RequestViewForBatch request : requestList) {
  orderService.processEachRequest(request);
}
```

In the service class the method is like this;

```
Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED, timeout = 100, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
  public void processEachRequest(RequestViewForBatch request) {
//update database
}
```

When executing the task, it gives me this error message

```
org.springframework.transaction.NestedTransactionNotSupportedException: Transaction manager does not allow nested transactions by default - specify 'nestedTransactionAllowed' property with value 'true'
```

but i don't know how to solve this error.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The tasklet step will be executed in a transaction driven by Spring Batch. You need to remove the `@Transactional` on your `processEachRequest` method.

You would need a fault-tolerant chunk-oriented step configured with a skip policy. In this case, only faulty items will be skipped. Please refer to the [Configuring Skip Logic](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#configuringSkip) section of the documentation. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/main/spring-batch-samples#chunk-scanning-sample).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try chunk-oriented coding!

Comment: I starting trying writing it in chunk-oriented model using ItemReader/ItemProcessor/ItemWriter, but in each loop I need to process many data in many different tables. In detail...
 1. Get all the records that needs to be processed from Table A/ 2.for each record, update several tables(TableA, Table B, Table C and so on)  and this process needs to be in one transaction. So I have no idea if this can be done with ItemReader/Processor/Writer.

Comment: Mahmoud Ben Hassine: Its not possible to call a service inside the writer that starts its own nested transaction?